# ExecuteNonQuery doesn't return value?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I am trying to write a common Save function and I am using `Dbcommand`. My code is:

```
private static int Save(CommandType commandtype, string commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters, bool p)
{
    int id = -1;

    using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = commandtype;
            command.CommandText = commandText;
            foreach(SqlParameter pa in commandParameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(pa);
            }
            connection.Open();
            id = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return id;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? The code saves the value in the database.

Comment: You haven't said what you're observing. You claim it "doesn't return value" - what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please delete the line in the SP    **SET NOCOUNT ON;** in the SP so you will get 
the value

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected.

If your SQL statement is something like

```
 insert into ... values ...
 select @@identity
```

Then you need to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.
look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

But I don't understand what do you mean when you said that the method ExecuteNonQuery should return value.
If you want to return a value you should use the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Execute Scalar returns only 1 row..and executenonquety returns affected rows only...
ExecuteNonQuery doesnt give u return values...

Comment: ya i mean it should be returning me the row affected after insert.anyhow i know what wrong stuff i did. In stored Proc i wrote SET NOCOUNT ON. i made is OFF and i got the row affected.